# Using sed to match text in the 5th field

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

So, I am trying to look for certain words in the 5th field of /etc/passwd.
For example:

```
jonesc:x:1053:1001:Cathy Jones:/export/home/jonesc:/bin/ksh
smiths:x:1049:1000:Sue Williams:/export/home/smiths:/bin/csh
smitha:x:1050:1001:Amy Smith:/export/home/smitha:/bin/bash
```

Lets say I am looking for the word 'Smith'? How would I look for it ONLY in the 5th field that contains the names, as opposed to looking through the entire line?

I can easily do this with awk, but I am asked to do this with sed instead.

What I'm asked to do is to output matches from /etc/passwd that contain Smith or Jones in the 5th field to a file called smith_jones.txt.

I have no problem with writing output to file with sed, I am just stuck with how I am supposed to look for only in the 5th field.
Awk would use $5, but I cannot find something similar with sed.

Not looking for a complete answer being handed to me, but rather a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Awk would be the right tool for the job:

```
awk '$5 ~ /smith|jones/{print}' /etc/passwd > output.txt
```

But since you are asking for a sed solution then you can use something like this:

```
sed -n '/[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:\(smith\|jones\)/p' /etc/passwd
```

Where each `[^:]*` will match everything but `:` zero or more times.

You can also repeat a previous pattern with the range meta sequence: `\{x,y\}`:

```
sed -n '/\([^:]*:\)\{4\}\(smith\|jones\)/p' /etc/passwd
```

As you can see this will help you simplify your regex even more.

`-n` is for no print by default and `/pattern/p` will print everything matching `pattern`

You might want to add another `[^:]*` before `\(smith\|jones\)` if you want to match the middle of the user name, eg:

```
sed -n '/\([^:]*:\)\{4\}[^:]*\(th\|es\)/p' /etc/passwd
```

Will match `Smith` and `Jones`.

As pointed out in the comments you can also use Extended Regular Expressions to avoid all those backslashes:

```
sed -E -n '/([^:]*:){4}(smith|jones)/p' /etc/passwd
```

Traditionally GNU sed used `-r` to enable ERE and BSD sed uses `-E`. GNU sed however support the `-E` flag even though it's undocumented.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I was not looking for a complete answer, your explanation helped me understand how you came up with the answer provided. I agree, I would have loved if I had a choice to use awk instead, it would have saved me quite some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sed -n '/^\([^:]*:\)\{4\}[^:]*\(Jones\|Smith\)/p' /etc/passwd
```

`^\([^:]*:\)\{4\}` matches the first four fields delimited with `:`, and thus the fifth field is matched against the names (Jones and Smith).

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this:

```
sed -n ":1
/^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*Smith[^:]*:.*$/ {p
n
b1}
/^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*Jones[^:]*:.*$/{p}"
```

`-n` instructs `sed` to not print anything

`:1` defines a label

`/^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*Smith[^:]*:.*$/` regex matches any string that contains `Smith` in the 5th field, where fields are separated with `:`.

`p` is a command that prints the current line.

`n` is a command that loads the next line into the buffer.

`b1` goto label `1`

`sed` reads the file one line at a time. The current line is stored into the buffer. If`Smith` is found in the 5th field the line is printed and the next line is stored into the buffer and it goes to label 1. Otherwise, if `Jones` is found in the 5th field then the line in the buffer is printed.

The test:

```
$ sed -n ":1
/^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*Smith[^:]*:.*$/ {p
n
b1}
/^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*Jones[^:]*:.*$/{p}" /etc/passwd >> smith_jones.txt

$ cat smith_jones.txt
jonesc:x:1053:1001:Cathy Jones:/export/home/jonesc:/bin/ksh
smitha:x:1050:1001:Amy Smith:/export/home/smitha:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Why is the loop necessary for Smith?

Comment: @anishsane if a line has a 5th field that contains both `Smith` and `Jones`, both `regex` are mathing. The `loop` avoid  such line to be printed twice.

Comment: You could do `{p;d}` to avoid loop in that case. But better, you can match both in a single regex...

Comment: @anishsane true. the `sed` on my box accepts `ERE` (I just realized) but the `| ` needs to be escaped. I will provide a new version after test.

Comment: @anishsane I did not update the answer because it was very close to andlrc ones. I leave mine as it is, for history. Thx for your remarks, I learnt something today !!! :)